# Aligning duplicates in Excel

Tags: excel

I have 3 columns in Excel. The data in first column are complete dates from given year in ascending order. In second column are also dates but in between these dates there can be a missing day. So if i place these dates next to each other they do no line up. And in third column there is some date that corresponds to the date in 2nd column. Now what i would like to do is to align those dates, and where there is no date in first column the row is empty.

I have already put some code together for excel to lign up the data, but i dont know how to align the dates together with the values in third column(C column). 
Here is my code: 
    =IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1;C:C;0));"";INDEX(C:C;MATCH(A1;C:C;0)))

Here is a visualization(the data in column A is all the dates in a given year. The data in column B and C must be moved together):

```
|     A    |     B     |     C     |
|1.1.2018  |3.1.2018   |12345      |
|2.1.2018  |14.1.2018  |54321      |
|3.1.2018  |2.2.2018   |56789      |
|4.1.2018  |2.1.2018   |11111      |
```

Desired output:

```
|     A    |     B     |     C     |
|1.1.2018  |           |           |
|2.1.2018  |2.1.2018   |11111      |
|3.1.2018  |3.1.2018   |12345      |
|4.1.2018  |           |           |
```

Comment: So column B dates can be in any order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your sample data this formula will search column B for the first instance of the date that is in column A and return the value from column C on that row.

In cell D1 and dragged down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C,MATCH($A1,$B:$B,0)),"")
```

`MATCH($A1,$B:$B,0)` will return the row number that the date appears in in column B.
`INDEX($C:C$,....)` will return the value from column C based on the row number returned by the `MATCH` function.
If nothing is found then an `#N/A` error occurs which is dealt with by the `IFERROR(.....,"")` function.